# Find the Greatest Number in a Stack Using only PUSH & POP Operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

Can anyone please help me with the Algorithm for this problem (its an Interview Question):

> You are given a stack. Devise an algorithm to find the maximum number
>   using PUSH/POP Operations only.

Comment: Do you mean "find the largest number, leaving the stack in its initial configuration?" Can we have multiple stacks?

Comment: Presumably you can also use comparisons -- otherwise, finding the maximum is going to be a bit challenging ;-)  Also, you're going to need a stack empty test -- otherwise, how could you tell when you've got all the data.   Are there any other constraints (i.e. does the stack have to be restored to its original state?

Comment: Yes, The initial configuration should be unchanged. We can use another stack as well.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Okay, thanks.   I've updated my answer to include an alternate solution using the new constraint (an unchanged stack) and the new resource (a second stack).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the lack of constraints in the original post, you can just pop off all the data and compute a running maximum:

```
if empty(st) -> raise exception
m <- pop(st)
while not empty(st)
    n <- pop(st)
    if n > m
        m <- n
```

Edit (with the new restriction that the original stack is unchanged and the new resource of a second available stack):

```
if empty(st) -> raise exception
m <- pop(st)
push(alt_st, m)
while not empty(st)
    n <- pop(st)
    push(alt_st, n)
    if n > m
        m <- n
while not empty(alt_st):
    n <- pop(alt_st)
    push(st, n)
```

Comment: No, the original stack should be unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Because original stack cannot be read-only (`Pop`, the only way to access the data, also modifies the stack), we have to consider that "the stack should be unchanged" restriction means that we have to restore it to its original state after we finish.

We can do it by using another stack in method proposed by Raymond Hettinger:

```
int get_max_from_stack(Stack stack) {
    int M = stack.pop();
    Stack aux;
    aux.push(M);
    while (!stack.empty()){
        int tmp = stack.pop();
        aux.push(tmp);
        M = max(M, tmp);
    };

    while (!aux.empty())
        stack.push(aux.pop());

    return M;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of tackling this problem, either you can make a function `get_max`which gives the maximum number in the stack, or you can maintain some extra information using which you can give the maximum number in the stack in `O(1)` operation but at the cost of `extra space`. I will give you the latter solution.

What you need to do is to have an `extra stack` that will have the maximum element of the stack at the top, for any configuration of the stack.

1. Whenever you push a number to your original stack, do the following for `max_stack`, compare the current value with the top of max_stack and push the greater one onto it.
2. When you pop a number simply pop the topmost number from the `max_stack`
3. When you need to find out the `max` value just pick the stack top from `max_stack`.

This way you can get the max number in `O(1)` time and the push and pop operations also remain `O(1)`. I could have give you the code but there is nothing much in it, as it is straight forward. For example if you push following numbers in the order

`5 - 2 - 6 - 8 - 1`

`max_stack` will contain

`5 - 5 - 6 - 8 - 8`

and as you `pop` of the numbers the current `max` will be at the top.

I hope the solution is clear.

Comment: Actually the more generally asked question how will you support `push`, `pop`, `get_max` and `get_min` operations in `O(1)` time for stack, or a similarly for a `queue`